# Quadratics with unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If $5x^2 – t = 4x$, and $x$ and $t$ are both positive real numbers. What is $x$ equal to?

How do you find $x$? Is there a specific formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$ax^2 + bx + c = 0,$$
then you can calculate $x$ to be $$x_{1,2} = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$

Comment: wow thanks forgot about the quadratic formula!! kept on thinking if it had something to do with the discriminant -.-

Comment: @hiiye Well, you still have to transform your equation into the standard form...

Answer (score 4):

Write your equation in the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0.\tag{1}$

Doing so gives you $5x^2-4x – t = 0.\tag{2}$

Now, knowing that to solve for and equation of this form $(1)$, we can use the quadratic equation: $$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

we have, for your equation $(2)$, $a = 5, \;b = -4,\; c = -t$

$$x = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{16+20t}}{10}$$

Only one solution results (the $+$ in the $\pm$), since $t>0$ and $x>0.$

Comment: The problem has exactly one solution, since it's required that $x>0$ and $t>0$.

Comment: further, the sum of the roots will be 4/5 and product will be -1/5, using this the equation reduces to only having t! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the quadratic formula:

> The solutions to $ax^2+bx+c = 0$ are

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$